# AWS EKS Workers never register with ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an AWS EKS cluster up and running, single worker is up and running our application. Loadbalancer was properly created in our private subnets using the service annotations and subnet tags. But, the worker node remains OutOfService. Just the default healthcheck with a ping.

Everything else appears to be working fine.  I just can't get the worker to pass the healthcheck.

EDIT: I have tried with an internet-facing ELB as well, same issue.   Verified that the worker instance security group is being altered to allow for all traffic from the load balancer, so it *should* be working, but it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.  At some point while testing, I had the wrong target port in the service.